# CentOS expanding directory

Tags: linux, centos, hard-drive

I currently have a file server, and all the files are installed in `/usr/local/nginx/html/`.

The setup is one hard disk with 1 TB of data. This 1 TB of storage is all used up.

I asked the guys to add two HDDs with 2 TB each. These new HDDs will be used for new storage of files. Now, if I mount these two new HDDs into `/usr/local/nginx/html/`, the current files in there will be deleted.

My goal is to expand the storage in `/usr/local/nginx/html/` without losing data in it. Would this be possible?

Comment: Did you consider using RAID on your server to protect against data loss (disk failure)?

Comment: I'm surprised no one has mentioned using LVM.

Comment: … or moving him over to FreeBSD and using ZFS. True enough

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way of moving the files over to the new mountpoint is:

```
# cd /usr/local/nginx/html
# vi /etc/fstab # (add the new disk to the fstab now so you don't forget!)
# mount /usr/local/nginx/html
# mv * /usr/local/nginx/html
```

And by the way, use RAID :)

Comment: +1, referencing current yet unreachable directory. Love it!

Comment: That's very clever. Took me a few seconds to work out how it could work. And yes - use RAID!

Comment: This is *terrible*, yet also, strangely wonderful...

Comment: Wow.. wonderful solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is evil or genius. Evil genius?

Answer (score 5):

The files wouldn't be deleted by mounting another device at `/usr/local/nginx/html` - they would just be masked beneath the mounted file system.

In such a situation, I would install the new disks, create appropriate file systems (can't help there - I don't use Linux), temporarily mount the new disk at, say, `/mnt` and move the data from `/usr/local/nginx/html` to `/mnt`. You can then unmount the new device, and mount it at `/usr/local/nginx/html` and all your current files will be available on the new disk, along with all that extra capacity.