# Need help recovering files after mounting new volume

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, data-recovery

So I used the guide in this answer to mount a new volume to /var/www:

[Allowing apache to access multiple volumes under AWS](https://serverfault.com/questions/537766/allowing-apache-to-access-multiple-volumes-under-aws)

However, after doing it, my /var/www appears to have been cleaned out. I know the files all still exist, because running a quick df shows no change in the disk usage in the original volume (/dev/xvda1). Where can I find these files? I really need to get them back.

Comment: What did you do with the files that were there?

Comment: I didn't do anything outside of the commands listed in the answer. There's a lost+found directory where the files were - could they be in there?

Comment: Unmount the new directory.

Comment: Wow, I was about to slam my head on my desk. Please make that an answer so I can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mounting a filesystem at a mount point hides any files that may be in that directory on the parent filesystem.

To resolve the issue, move your old files somewhere else temporarily and create a new empty directory to hold the mount point. Then move the files into the new filesystem.

```
sudo -i
mv /var/www /var/www.old
mkdir /var/www
mount /dev/xvd** /var/www
mv -v /var/www.old/* /var/www
rmdir /var/www.old
```

Comment: @MikeyB's answer is quite elegant in its own right, but this is a much more succinct explanation of the OP's issue.

Answer (score 6):

[Michael Hampton's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/541164/2101) is most correct, though I've [posted about this before](https://serverfault.com/a/372063/2101).

The easiest way of moving the files over to the new mountpoint is:

```
# cd /var/www
# vi /etc/fstab # (add the new disk to the fstab now so you don't forget!)
# mount /var/www
# mv * /var/www
```

Comment: Evil genius, yes. Though it's not immediately clear there what's going on.

Comment: I like teaching a man to fish.